# String Conversion in Javascript (Decimal to Binary)

Tags: javascript

A newbie here! Wondering why the following conversion fails!

```js
var num = prompt("Enter num");
alert(num.toString(2));
```

If num input is 32. I get 32 as num alert message too.

Comment: That's what I'd expect to happen. What are you expecting this to do that it doesn't do?

Comment: To convert 32 as a string that displays the binary number!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

try

```
(+num).toString(2)
```

,

```
Number(num).toString(2)
```

or

```
parseInt(num, 10).toString(2)
```

Any of those should work better for you.

The issue is that the `toString` method of javascript `Number` objects overrides the `toString` method of `Object` objects to accept an optional radix as an argument to provide the functionality you are looking for. The `String` object does not override `Object`'s `toString` method, so any arguments passed in are ignored.

For more detailed information about these objects, see the docs at Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods

or W3 schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: So this does the same right? It converts the string 32 into an integer and then do the binary conversion..

Comment: why not just decnum.toString(2) without all the foreplay

Comment: @foreyez because `prompt` returns a String, and String::toString doesn't take a radix

Comment: I mean "var decnum=123; alert(decnum.toString(2));"

Comment: @foreyez sure, that'll work. The question is about a string (that just happens to called `num`) though.

Comment: num..toString() - **mind double dot!** will also work same as Number(num).toString(2)

Comment: @shershen that doesn't work in node 4.x or latest chrome

Comment: 2..toString() == "2" in latest (7-12-2015) Google Chrome 47.0

Comment: @shershen ah ok -- num is a sring in the question here. The double dot only seems to work with numbers

Answer (score 20):

With this function you can specify length of the output.

For example `decbin(7,4)` produces `0111`.

```
function decbin(dec,length){
  var out = "";
  while(length--)
    out += (dec >> length ) & 1;    
  return out;  
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/iKalUga/1/)

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution that does not use parseInt, but rather a method that shows the logic behind the conversion of decimal to binary.

This method prints the bits to the array which you may later print out if you wish:

```
var number = 156;
var converted = [];

while(number>=1) {
    converted.unshift(number%2);
    number = Math.floor(number/2);
}
```

The converted array will now appear like so:

**[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]**

which of course converts back to 156.

Answer (score 6):

/**
 Convert a decimal number to binary
 **/

```
var toBinary = function(decNum){
    return parseInt(decNum,10).toString(2);
}
```

/**
  Convert a binary number to decimal
 **/

```
var toDecimal = function(binary) {
    return parseInt(binary,2).toString(10);
}
```

Finally use it

```
var num= prompt("Enter num"); 
alert(toBinary(num));
```

Answer (score 5):

Cast it to an integer first. At the moment you're converting a string to it's binary representation.

```
num = +num;
```

Comment: Convert it to an int. Then Javascript can convert it to a binary string.

Comment: Okay. please mark either of the answers as correct. Glad we could help.