# Convert Decimal to Binary in AngularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert decimal to binary numbers using AngularJS

```
let decimal = 128;
let binary = parseInt(decimal.toString(), 2); // returning 1
```

Comment: try function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Conversion in Javascript (Decimal to Binary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132905/string-conversion-in-javascript-decimal-to-binary)

Comment: @RahalKanishka, Thanks working.

Comment: There is no decimal here. `decimal` is already in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `toString()` and not `parseInt`. This line of code work

```
let decimal = 128;
var toBinary = (+decimal).toString(2);
console.log(toBinary);
```

Comment: You can also upvote the answer so that it can depict that the answer has been really useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will convert numbers to the base 2 positional numeral system    `return (decimal >>> 0).toString(2)`

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way

```
(128).toString(2); //result is 10000000
```

### Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Convert  binary number  from 128.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (128).toString(2); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't you see the comment in the question the OP has already got the solution for this then why are you adding the same thing again in different way?

Comment: I just posted single line of code instead of other answers. Answers is should be **better** to solve the problem

Comment: What about all that HTML and the button and click. They are irrelevant in this case. Why did not you added console.log() simple as that, if you are really worried about simplicity?